# ConstraintLayout not wrapping multiline EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, multiline, android-constraintlayout

My `ConstraintLayout` (which is inside a `CardView`) is not wrapping the contents properly in height. The contents includes an `EditText` which is one line but expands to multiple lines as the user writes text. The `ConstraintLayout` is sized on screen as if the multiple lines (up to 3 in this case) are already there. Based on [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.html#constrainedHeight), it seems setting `constrainedHeight=true` would solve the problem, but I don't know where or how to do that in the xml.

Anyone know how make the `ConstraintLayout` height shrink down to the correct size of the Edit text?

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:inputType="text|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:lines="3"
            android:maxLength="200"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:minLines="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Post your full layout, because it seems like other views are affecting it. And why use constraint layout if there is only one view, you can directly put the edittext inside the card without wrapping it in constraint layout

Comment: Got any solution? I have similar issue

Answer (score 0):

try use `maxHeight` on editext, for me solved issue.